# Combinatorics: how do you apply multiset theory to solve problem about items in a bag?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Problem: There are 10 fruits in a bag, they can be apple, orange, peach or mix of them. How many different possible combinations in the bag?

This problem is in our section dealing with both multiset theory and inclusion and exclusion principle. Which method am I supposed to use (or am I supposed to use both methods) to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Multisets, or equivalently Stars abd Bars. We are looking for the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=10$ in non-negative integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be the number of apples, $o$ be the number of peaches, $p$ be the number of peaches.

We have the following system:

$\begin{cases} a + o + p = 10\\
0\leq a\\
0\leq o\\
0\leq p\end{cases}$

This should be a known problem form.  If it isn't, consider another scenario.

Lay down a sequence of 10 $\star$'s and 2 $|$'s.  Put the number of apples into your cart as there are stars to the left of the first bar.  Put as many oranges into your cart as there are stars inbetween the first and second bar.  Finally, put as many peaches into your cart as there are after the second bar.

Convince yourself that there are as many sequences of stars and bars as there are ways of putting fruit in your basket.

The point of this appearing in the section for multisets is that we do not care in what order these appear in the basket, nor do we care that there are repititions.

Comment: Wow, I've spent so many hours trying to figure this out, and it turns out to be so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly stars-and-bars, e.g.
$$\overbrace{*\; *\; *}^{\text{apples}}\; \bigl| \; 
\overbrace{*\; *\;*\;*}^{\text{oranges}}\;\bigl|\;
\overbrace{*\;*\;*}^{\text{peaches}} $$
which gives
$$\binom {10+2}2=66$$
The "$2$" refers to the "bars" or dividers separating the fruits. The problem then reduces to the number of ways to place the dividers. For $n$ types of fruits, the number of dividers is $n-1$.